Qemu does not emulate ast2600-evb from binary file: failed to read the initial flash content
I have to emulate IPMI system for super server SYS-110P-WTR. To reach this target, I tried to repeat experience of these people. I installed qemu-9.0.0, and tried to do this command:
qemu-system-arm -m 256 -M ast2600-evb -nographic \
-drive file=./BMC_X12AST2600-ROT-5201MS_20240313_01.04.04_STDsp.bin,format=raw,if=mtd \
-net nic \
-net user,hostfwd=::2443-:443,hostname=qemu

And I catch this error:
qemu-system-arm: failed to read the initial flash content

But there isn't this problem with file of BMCX11 (AST-2400)
qemu-system-arm -m 128 -M supermicrox11-bmc -nographic \
> -drive file=./BMC_X11AST2400-3101MS_20230810_1.68_STDsp.bin,format=raw,if=mtd \
> -net nic \
> -net user,hostfwd=::2443-:443,hostname=qemu
qemu-system-arm: warning: nic ftgmac100.1 has no peer

U-Boot 2009.01-00024-gc2e4306-dirty (11月 07 2018 - 09:31:15) ASPEED (v.0.21) 

I2C:   ready
DRAM:  128 MB
Flash: 32 MB
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

I work in virtual VBox machine Ubuntu 20.04.6
Please, tell me, how to fix this, or suggest me any solutions or actions to emulate.
I tried to repeat this advise, but they didn't help. Of course, I tried to make an image file by OpenBMC, but it gave out a stupid errors like "tar doesn't exists in directory buildtools".

How big is your firmware file? This machine is equipped with 64 MB flash, and the backing file must match that. If the file is shorter than that, you need to pad it to that size. There's a linked question which deals with it, though it is not entirely obvious in that.

@AndreyTurkin His size is 49 Mb. Please, tell, how fix this? I thought that dd will help me...but...
Maybe, I'm not so clever to do this...and all is simple

Just like in the linked article, expect with different sizes. dd if=/dev/zero of=flash.bin bs=1K count=64K && dd if=BMC_X12AST2600-ROT-5201MS_20240313_01.04.04_STDsp.bin of=flash.bin bs=4096 conv=notrunc - that should make flash.bin which is exactly 64MB in size. Use that file as a flash backing storage

@AndreyTurkin Great!!! Really, It's works. But now I will wait a kernel start...hope, the rest will be like greased lightning...You decided my first problem, thanks!
But it's too strange for me...it's starting too long...
eec
Verifying Hash Integrity ... sha256+ OK
Loading loadables from 0x21ffc4ec to 0x9d000000
Loading Kernel Image ... OK
Loading Device Tree to 8457f000, end 8458f4f4 ... OK
Starting kernel ...
It's 6 minutes left from this message...

Andrey told me a solution of my problem - I just had to copy content of my boot file to flash.bin  with byte filling up to 64MB:
dd if=/dev/zero of=flash.bin bs=1K count=64K && dd if=bootfile.bin of=flash.bin bs=4096 conv=notrunc

